# Sum NSMutableArray elements in a dynamic way

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray, in this format: (<-x-> is a separator that I put here to render easy to carry out transactions sum)

```
23,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM
89,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM
13,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM

53,00 <-x-> 22/10/2019 21:09:05 AM

93,00 <-x-> 23/10/2019 12:12:45 PM
83,00 <-x-> 23/10/2019 12:12:45 PM
```

As you can see, my array have prices and the date time, All that would do is, find a way to get all the fields in which the day are equals and go sum all the price values, and put the complete sum in other Array with the date time, example:

```
125,00  <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM // 23 + 89 + 13 = 125,00 + date time that are equals
53,00   <-x-> 22/10/2019 21:09:05 AM // 53 only but not have another value with the same date time
176,00     <-x-> 23/10/2019 12:12:45 PM // 93 + 83 = 176,00 + date time that are equals
```

Well, I have not tried anything because I do not know where to start, so I'm here to ask you guys to help me solve this puzzle, I will be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Each line, like `23,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM`, is a string?

Comment: You are not describing this well. What is in the array? Strings? Custom objects with an NSNumber and an NSDate? If it's a string exactly as you've shown, you have a fairly complex bit of work to do. You could use the indexesOfObjectsPassingTest: method to find objects that match your target date. Then you'd take the resulting index set and pass it to enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:options:usingBlock: to run code on each object that matches your date string

Comment: Ok, so you could combine my suggestions (above) with @random's code for separating the parts of your string. Note that you will probably also have to create an NSDateFormatter to convert your date string back to an NSDate, then use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents to check the date to see if it matches your target date.

Answer (score 1):

Every time that you find yourself in need of a separator like `<-x->`, it is time to use a better data structure than a string. This could be a dictionary or a custom object.
In both cases you could use KVC collection operator [`@sum`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-178593):

```
NSNumber *totalPrice = [dates valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.price"];
```

---

I wrote a sample code where I use a wrapper class that takes the string in your format and creates a wrapper object to hold the price and the date, as NSNumber and NSDate.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Wrapper : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *price;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;

-(id)initWithString:(NSString *) string;
@end

@implementation Wrapper

-(id)initWithString:(NSString *) string
{
    if(self = [super init]){
        [self processString:string];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)processString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSArray *array = [[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] componentsSeparatedByString:@" <-x-> "];

    static NSNumberFormatter *nf;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        nf.decimalSeparator = @",";
    });

    NSNumber *n = [nf numberFromString:array[0]];
    self.price = n;

    static NSDateFormatter *df;
    static dispatch_once_t dfOnceToken;
    dispatch_once(&dfOnceToken, ^{
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        df.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
        df.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
    });
    NSDate *d = [df dateFromString:array[1]];
    self.date = d;

}

@end



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray *strings = @[
                             @"23,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM",
                             @"89,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM",
                             @"13,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM"
                             ];
        NSMutableArray *objects = [@[] mutableCopy];

        for (NSString *string in strings) {
            [objects addObject:[[Wrapper alloc] initWithString:string]];
        }

        NSNumber *totalPrice = [objects valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.price"];
        NSLog(@"%@", totalPrice);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

output: `125`

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give you exact code but this is how you do the guts of it:

```
NSString *string = @"83,00 <-x-> 23/10/2019 12:12:45 PM";

//We first want to split the string based on the ' <-x-> ', we could just use NSString's substringWithRange but if the leading numberical values are ever larger than 4 digits it would break. So in order to keep it flexible we split it in half.
NSArray *subStrings = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" <-x-> "];
NSLog(@"%@", subStrings);


//When we seperate the first value in subStrings will be "23,00"
NSString *numericalValues = subStrings[0];
NSLog(@"numbericalValues: `%@`", numericalValues);


//We get the date out of the subString compoenents NSString's substringWithRange since the date string will always be the same length.
NSString *trimmedDateString = [subStrings[1] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
NSLog(@"trimmedDateSTring: `%@`", trimmedDateString);


/*
 So now we have turned this:

 23,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM

 into this: 

 23,00
 20/09/2019


 You can use this same logic in a loop to compare date's and convert the 23,00 into a value you can add.
*/
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use a separator string of @" <-x-> "? (including the spaces)

Comment: @DuncanC You sir are absolutely right, i've updated my answer, much much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

In broad strokes, you want to parse out the components of the string, group the elements by their date and add up the dates in each group. A dictionary is a good way of doing this. In pseudocode:

```
NSDictionary results

for string in array:
  date = split(" <-x-> ", string)[0]
  priceString = split(" <-x-> ", string)[1]
  price = split(",", pricesString)[0]
  results[date] = results[date] or 0
  results[date] += price
```

Answer (score -1):

I try and try hard, and finally I got my answer, I create the code below and it works perfectly the way in which I expected, Thanks everyone helped me!

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray * array01 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"23,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM",@"89,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM",@"13,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM",@"53,00 <-x-> 22/10/2019 21:09:05 AM",@"53,00 <-x-> 22/10/2019 21:09:05 AM",@"93,00 <-x-> 23/10/2019 12:12:45 PM",@"83,00 <-x-> 23/10/2019 12:12:45 PM",@"83,00 <-x-> 23/10/2019 12:12:45 PM",@"83,00 <-x-> 23/10/2019 1:12:45 PM",@"23,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM",@"23,00 <-x-> 20/09/2019 12:43:23 PM",nil];

        NSMutableArray * array02 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"%@",array01);

        int index2 = 0;

        for(int x=0;x<[array01 count];x++){


            if([array02 count] == 0){

                [array02 addObject:array01[x]];

            }else{

                NSMutableArray *lstaInfo02;

                if([array02 count] == index2){
                    //Array count menor que index 2 isso quer dizer que -> Passamos para uma data diferente

                    NSLog(@"Apos esta linha apareçera um erro! array02 contagem -> %d index2 contagem -> %d",array02.count,index2);

                    index2 = index2 - 1;

                }

                lstaInfo02 = [[array02[index2] componentsSeparatedByString:@"<-x->"] mutableCopy];

                NSMutableArray *lstaInfo01 = [[array01[x] componentsSeparatedByString:@"<-x->"] mutableCopy];

                NSString *string1 = lstaInfo02[1];
                NSString *string2 = lstaInfo01[1];


                if([string1 isEqualToString:string2]){

                    NSString *objects = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f <-x->%@",[lstaInfo02[0] floatValue] + [lstaInfo01[0] floatValue], string2];

                    NSLog(@"SUM -> %@ + %@ = %@",lstaInfo01[0],lstaInfo02[0],objects);

                    [array02 replaceObjectAtIndex:index2 withObject:objects];

                    NSLog(@"%@",array02);

                    if([array02 count] > 1){

                    index2++;

                    }

                }else{
                    [array02 addObject:array01[x]];

                    //O problema se encontra aqui quando vai fazer o ++

                    index2++;

                }


            }

        }


                    NSLog(@"%@",array02);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes rs You need to read, and I'm so complicated with him... He works but if I put more price and datas, the compiles get errors